# how can i get user notifications with the new Graph API

Tags: facebook

im making switch to the new Graph API , and i try to replace all the rest api with the new Graph api
reading the docs i saw i have some kind of real time function ( im not sure its related to getting the user
notifications ) that suppose to return me callback .
but im my case i like to invoke simple http command and get the user notification like ( like the old notification api's )
how can i do it now ?
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

A GraphAPI-way: you can access notifications through [`USER_ID/notifications`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#notifications), it requires the [`manage_notifications`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) permission.

[Graph API Explorer example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/notifications)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get all recent notifications *including* read notifications via Graph API, call:

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/notifications?include_read=true
```

This can be useful for testing purposes.

Answer (score 8):

Update: **It is no longer possible to read the user notifications**.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications/

Answer (score 2):

<del>As of Aug 1 2010, there are still no methods for notifications in the new Graph API (I'm not sure if there are any plans for migrating that). You need to use the old REST API for that.</del>

Use FB.api in place of old REST API. It could be something like this:

```
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'notifications.get'
  },
  function(response) {
    alert("Number of unread messages: " + response.messages.unread);
  }
);
```