# Send FB user a notification via App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm getting an App access token via the Facebook API.

```
$app_id = "ID";
$app_secret = "SECRET";
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&client_secret=".$app_secret."&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

When $app_token is echoed, the following is displayed

```
access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx // access token x'ed out for security.
```

The "ID" is equal to my application ID (which I'm not silly enough to write). There's a vertical bar that separates the ID from another alphanumeric string.

I'm not very experienced with this aspect of the API, particularly doing what involves App access token rather than user access tokens.

So, when I tried to send a test notification in a php script

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_user_id."/notifications?href=".$url."&".$app_token;
$result = file_get_contents($url);
```

$result gives me an error message as such:

```
{"error":{"message":"A user access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":102}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/, you should using HTTP POST requests to send notification to the user of your apps, not HTTP GET requests.

Comment: yet another reason curl > file_get_contents :-)

Comment: Hi, Question: How do I get the notification ID? in response you only get success:true

Comment: @rayman No point your app get the notification ID from the response. Why your app need to deal with this notification ID? If you are willing to get the notification on behalf of the user, then check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712443/how-can-i-get-user-notifications-with-the-new-graph-api

Comment: I am willing to check for example the impression rate per specific notification. how can I do that?? I need to pass somehow the notification ID no?

Comment: @rayman Read this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications?locale=en_GB#insights and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/app_insights?locale=en_GB

Comment: Yes I read that. found total impressions: app_notification_impressions. I want to see impressions per specific notification. using ref didnt work. getting always same result

Comment: @rayman The documentation stated, "Just pass a ref parameter with a custom key name when posting your notification. All notifications with the same ref will be grouped together in Insights, and can be selected via the Story Types menu." You can pass ref per specific notification if you want to.

Comment: Oh thats what I did. when I send the notification I added &ref=333 and when I am executing again the insights api this way: graph.facebook.api.../{app-id}/app_insights/app_notification_impressions?ref=333&access_token={Access-token}   i am getting the same results!

Comment: Guess I didnt understand how to add "breakdowns" to my http get request. could you assist me with that?

Comment: I am almost there. just dont know how to add ref: /app_insights/app_notification_impressions?breakdowns=['ref']&access_token={access-token}. I get result: "breakdowns": {
        "ref": "no_ref_specified"
      }

Comment: @rayman I believe you can get the job done by referring the doc. I'm not sure how long, but insight might need some time to update, check this http://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-for-your-Facebook-Insights-to-be-updated

Comment: I have problem with the api. I dont know how to pass the ref id in that form. I get this error:  { "ref": "no_ref_specified" } –