# How can i send a Facebook App Request with access token and graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

can i send a request notification to a specific user on facebook using access token

i searched on facebook developers pages ..

they shared this ..

POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?access_token= … &template= … &href= …

but the user who resive the notfication must be accessed the app before ..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests

my question is .. can i send a notfication invitation from app to user

not with invitaion dialog .. ?

Comment: This feature has been abused a lot and hence been redacted by Facebook long since. However your current app users can send notifications/invitation to new users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send FB user a notification via App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722605/send-fb-user-a-notification-via-app)

Comment: @salman so its imposible to send a invitation without the the invitaion doc ?? .. 
is there any other way to invite users by graph ? like note or event invitation ? 

the link doesnt help im asking about invitations

Comment: Yes it seems sending is impossible unless the same user has accessed the app before. That is why popular Facebook games make players send invites to others by rewarding them in game.

Comment: How can I found access_token for sending request to facebook api?