# User notifications on Facebook API for Android

Tags: android, facebook

Is it possible to retrieve user notifications using Facebook API for Android?

If so, what kind of information can be received?

Kindly post an example of how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **receive notifications** from a user:
You could also look on this question:
[how can i get user notifications with the new Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712443/how-can-i-get-user-notifications-with-the-new-graph-api)

If you want to **send notifications** to a user:

Look at the Facebook Developer page: There you can find some good explinations, example codes and so on:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/

```
If so, what kind of information can be received?
```

You can make you own picture in front of the notification and set your own text (look at the link above for more information)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! But I guess you've got the question wrong. I want to **retrieve** the notifications of a user who is logged in, not send notifications to other users.

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault... Do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712443/how-can-i-get-user-notifications-with-the-new-graph-api ??